# Wordpress / Woocommerce Bulk Actions - Sort Dropdown

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, dropdown, action, bulk

how can I sort the dropdown list in Woocommerce under the orders section?
For example, I want the "mark as paid" before another action - how can I sort them in a specific order? Thanks for any help.

EDIT: We added this as snippet, but it only brings "Delete" from bulk actions to end of dropdown list - how can we bring others to top?

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-gzd-shipments', 'sort_bulk_action', PHP_INT_MAX );
function sort_bulk_action( $bulk_actions ) {
    $process = $bulk_actions['delete']; 
    unset($bulk_actions['delete']);
    $bulk_actions['delete'] = $process;
    return $bulk_actions;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We added this as snippet, but it only brings "Delete" from bulk actions to end of dropdown list - how can we bring others to top?

Comment: `add_filter( 'bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-gzd-shipments', 'sort_bulk_action', PHP_INT_MAX );
function sort_bulk_action( $bulk_actions ) {
 $process = $bulk_actions['delete']; 
 unset($bulk_actions['delete']);
 $bulk_actions['delete'] = $process;
 return $bulk_actions;
}`